# vue2-datepicker disable days range date

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

I using vue2-datepicker. I have range of date:

**from:** 02-10-2019

**to:** 07-10-2019

I need disabled all days without this range.

I used method `disabled-days` but I don't know how I can declare range in this function. I can only disable individual days, for example:

```
<date-picker
    v-model="dateAccept"
    range
    :disabled-days="disabledDates2"
    valueType="format">
</date-picker>

disabledDates2: [
    new Date(2019, 10, 2), new Date(2019, 10, 6)
]
```

In vue-datepicker (version 1) isset function `:disabled-dates` but not working in version 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found resolve. Just I used in `data` function:

```
disabledBefore: new Date(2019, 10, 2),
disabledAfter: new Date(2019, 10, 6)
```

And in datepicker:

```
<date-picker
    v-model="dateAccept"
    range
    valueType="format"
    :not-before="disabledBefore"
    :not-after="disabledAfter">
</date-picker>
```

Answer (score 3):

have a look at [ref](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/issues/451)

you can use the method

```
<data-picker ... :disabled-date="disabledRange" range></data-picker>
        
methods: {
     ...
     disabledRange: function (date) {
         return date < new Date(2019, 10, 2) || date > new Date(2019, 10, 6);
     }
     ...
}
```